# I can't populate H2 database with values form CSV file

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, jpa, h2

I am trying to populate an H2 database with values from a CSV file, like this:

```
@Component
public class DBWriterOrder implements ItemWriter<OrderEntity> {

private OrderRepository orderRepository;

@Autowired
public DBWriterOrder(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
    this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
}

@Override
public void write(List<? extends OrderEntity> orders) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Data Saved for Orders: " + orders);
    orderRepository.saveAll(orders);

     }
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class ProcessorOrder implements ItemProcessor<OrderEntity, OrderEntity> {

public SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

@Override
public OrderEntity process(OrderEntity orderEntity) throws Exception {

    Date deliveryDate = sdf.parse(orderEntity.getDeliveryDate().toString());
    long deliveryDateInMillis = deliveryDate.getTime();
    orderEntity.setDeliveryDate(deliveryDateInMillis);

    Date lastUpdated = sdf.parse(orderEntity.getLastUpdated().toString());
    long lastUpdatedInMillis = lastUpdated.getTime();
    orderEntity.setLastUpdated(lastUpdatedInMillis);


    return orderEntity;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfigOrder {

@Bean
public Job jobOrder(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
               StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
               ItemReader<OrderEntity> itemReader,
               ItemProcessor<OrderEntity, OrderEntity> itemProcessor,
               ItemWriter<OrderEntity> itemWriter
) {

    Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("ETL-file-load")
            .<OrderEntity, OrderEntity>chunk(100)
            .reader(itemReader)
            .processor(itemProcessor)
            .writer(itemWriter)
            .build();


    return jobBuilderFactory.get("ETL-Load")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(step)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<OrderEntity> itemReaderOrder() {

    FlatFileItemReader<OrderEntity> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/orders.csv"));
    flatFileItemReader.setName("CSV-Reader");
    flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapperOrder());
    return flatFileItemReader;
}

@Bean
public LineMapper<OrderEntity> lineMapperOrder() {

    DefaultLineMapper<OrderEntity> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();

    lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
    lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
    lineTokenizer.setNames("id","destination","deliveryDate","statusOrder","lastUpdated");

    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<OrderEntity> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(OrderEntity.class);

    defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
    defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

    return defaultLineMapper;
   }

}
```

---

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/loadOrder")
public class OrderLoadController {

@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncherOrder;

@Autowired
Job jobOrder;

@GetMapping
public BatchStatus load() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {


    Map<String, JobParameter> maps = new HashMap<>();
    maps.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    JobParameters parameters = new JobParameters(maps);
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherOrder.run(jobOrder, parameters);

    System.out.println("JobExecution: " + jobExecution.getStatus());

    System.out.println("Batch is Running...");
    while (jobExecution.isRunning()) {
        System.out.println("...");
    }

    return jobExecution.getStatus();
    }
}
```

---

Also this is my entity class:

```
@Entity(name = "orders")
@Data
public class OrderEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private DestinationEntity destination;

private Long deliveryDate;

@Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
private OrderStatus statusOrder;

private Long lastUpdated;

}
```

---

And this is my CSV file:

```
id,destination,deliveryDate,statusOrder,lastUpdated
1,Ploiesti,15-12-2021,NEW,15-12-2021
2,Ploiesti,15-12-2021,NEW,15-12-2021
3,Pitesti,15-12-2021,NEW,15-12-2021
4,Pitesti,15-12-2021,NEW,15-12-2021
5,Pitesti,15-12-2021,NEW,15-12-2021
```

---

When I call the endpoint localhost:8082/loadController, my DB instead of being populated it remains empty and all I got is this error in the console:

```
 org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 2 in resource=[file [C:\Users\ALEX\Desktop\FinalProject\demo\src\main\resources\orders.csv]], input=[1,Ploiesti,15-12-2021,NEW,15-12-2021]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:189) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]

 Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException: 
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 3 errors
 Field error in object 'target' on field 'lastUpdated': rejected value [15-12-2021]; codes [typeMismatch.target.lastUpdated,typeMismatch.lastUpdated,typeMismatch.java.lang.Long,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [target.lastUpdated,lastUpdated]; arguments []; default message [lastUpdated]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long' for property 'lastUpdated'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "15-12-2021"]
 Field error in object 'target' on field 'destination': rejected value [Ploiesti]; codes [typeMismatch.target.destination,typeMismatch.destination,typeMismatch.com.example.demo.destination.DestinationEntity,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [target.destination,destination]; arguments []; default message [destination]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.demo.destination.DestinationEntity' for property 'destination'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.demo.destination.DestinationEntity' for property 'destination': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
 Field error in object 'target' on field 'deliveryDate': rejected value [15-12-2021]; codes [typeMismatch.target.deliveryDate,typeMismatch.deliveryDate,typeMismatch.java.lang.Long,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [target.deliveryDate,deliveryDate]; arguments []; default message [deliveryDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long' for property 'deliveryDate'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "15-12-2021"]
```

---

In the end, my question is what should I do and how should I do to get things done?
I would prefer a full code solution because I am not sufficiently advanced to solve this on my own, only with indications.

Comment: start by actually reading the error message. You are trying to write a String into a field that isn't a String

Comment: @Stultuske I understand the error message and why it appears, what I do not know is what should I do so I can make the program work

Comment: How are you expecting to turn string 'Ploiesti' into an instance of DestinationEntity - where is that code, as that is what isn't happening and causing you this exception.

Comment: And '15-12-2021' is not a `Long`

Comment: @Chris I do have code for turning those dates in long values, and still the error

Comment: @Mansoor rather than telling what it is and it is not, could you give me at least some guidance if not a code solution

Comment: because it isn't being called - and it does not make sense. Why do yo have to convert orderEntity.getDeliveryDate() to a string to turn it into a long? And you don't have anything being executed I saw posted above that can possibly handle turning  string 'Ploiesti' into an instance of DestinationEntity, which is also mentioned in the error.

Comment: @Chris what exactly isn't being called?

Comment: Try using `FieldSetMapper` like below

Comment: It is your code - shouldn't you tell me? Where is the code you have that converts the date strings into a long, and how are you sure it is being called?

Comment: @Chris that code is in ProcessorOrder

Comment: @Mansoor like below where?

Comment: Check answers..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a custom `FieldSetMapper` because you need not only convert `String` into `Date` and then into `Long` but also lookup `DestinationEntity` by its name. Here is an example that converts `String` into `Date`

```
public class PersonFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Person> {

  @Override
  public Person mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
    return new Person(fieldSet.readLong("id"),
            fieldSet.readString("firstName"),
            fieldSet.readString("lastName"),
            fieldSet.readDate("birthdate", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
  }
}
```

Example taken from here https://www.dineshonjava.com/spring-batch-read-from-csv-and-write-to-relational-db/

You also need to somehow add a `Map<String, DestinationEntity>` property to this `FieldSetMapper` to lookup `DestinationEntity`

Comment: where I should use this?

Comment: Inside `lineMapperOrder()` method you need to replace `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<OrderEntity> fieldSetMapper` with your custom implementation of `FieldSetMapper`

Comment: also that example seems different from what I have, I do not know what to implement that code without breaking mine even more

Comment: and this custom mapper class should be used instead of my Processor class, or where should I create it?

Comment: You can create it just in `lineMapperOrder()` method.

Comment: and it will deal with converting a string into date and then into long?

Comment: You will still need to write actual. code that *will deal with converting a string into date and then into long*

Comment: And how should I use that code because FieldSet does not accept custom methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FieldSetMapper like below and replace Mapper from your code. Use index based reads for each field. Like `id` will be *0* index

```
public class OrderEntityMapper implements FieldSetMapper<OrderEntity> {

@Override
public OrderEntity mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
    OrderEntity order=new OrderEntity();
    order.setId(fieldSet.readLong(0));
    // other fields
    return order;
}
```

Then replace `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<OrderEntity> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>()` like

```
@Bean
public LineMapper<OrderEntity> lineMapperOrder() {

    DefaultLineMapper<OrderEntity> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();

    lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
    lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
    lineTokenizer.setNames("id","destination","deliveryDate","statusOrder","lastUpdated");

      defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
    defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new OrderEntityMapper());

    return defaultLineMapper;
   }

}
```

Comment: you say that I shoul replace my ProcessorOrder class?

Comment: and it will map properly if I use this? because the problem for example at dates seems  to be  that it tries to add a string where a long is required

Comment: Can you test it.

Comment: Use fields to read int, String, date, long etc.

Comment: I do not understand how it will give me the desired results, I am sorry but I think this is beyond what I can do

Comment: `    defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new OrderEntityMapper());` adding only this line? This is trivial.

Comment: Read the OrderEntityMapper in my answer.

Comment: Adding a line of code is not a problem, the problem is that I do not know how to make that FieldSet to do my job, transforming from string to date and then to long, also changing the destinations string into a Destination object